# How to create a for loop that goes through all diagonal possibilities of a list?

Tags: python, list

### Context

How would you find words in this list diagonally? Note: To show that a word has been found, it can be replaced by any character such as '-'

```
grid =   ["HXXWXXXXXD",
          "XOXXOXXXOX",
          "XXRXXCXGXX",
          "XXXSXXXXXT",
          "XXXXEXXXEX"]
```

I figured that *all possibilities* of diagonals in the grid are:

- Going downwards and left
- Going downwards and right
- Going upwards and left
- Going upwards and right

The words to find, in this instance would be:

```
words = ["HORSE","COW","DOG","ET"] # don't ask
```

### How I found words vertically and horizontally

Finding words diagonally seems much more difficult than horizontally or vertically. When finding words horizontally, I could just loop through each `row` in `grid` and each `word` in `words`. I could then replace `word` in `row` with a symbol `* len(word)`to illustrate that it had been found. Vertically, I rotated the grid 90° clockwise and then did the same process of looping through the lists horizontally. I then rotated the list back to its original state.

What different solutions are there to finding words diagonally?

Comment: Austin It should only look for items that are in the list of words to find. So `"GOD"` should not count as being Found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transform the list by shifting each of the string as list by 1 more than the last - and fill the created space with filler (Using `'0'` in this case):

```
mearray = np.array([[e for e in g] for g in grid])
words = ["HORSE","COW","DOG","ET"] # don't ask
```

I used `numpy` because I'm more used to it and it's easier to show here, but it could certainly be done in regular list comprehension. After this, your array is now a numpy array:

```
[['H' 'X' 'X' 'W' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'D']
 ['X' 'O' 'X' 'X' 'O' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'O' 'X']
 ['X' 'X' 'R' 'X' 'X' 'C' 'X' 'G' 'X' 'X']
 ['X' 'X' 'X' 'S' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'T']
 ['X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'E' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'E' 'X']]
```

Transform this by adding in shifting fillers:

```
leng = len(mearray)
def pad_with(vector, pad_width, iaxis, kwargs):
    pad_value = kwargs.get('padder', '0')
    vector[:pad_width[0]] = pad_value
    vector[-pad_width[1]:] = pad_value
    return vector
np.array([np.pad(mearray[i], (leng-i, i+1), pad_with) for i in range(leng)])
```

Your array is now:

```
[['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'H' 'X' 'X' 'W' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'D' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' 'X' 'O' 'X' 'X' 'O' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'O' 'X' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' 'X' 'X' 'R' 'X' 'X' 'C' 'X' 'G' 'X' 'X' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'S' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'T' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'E' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'E' 'X' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']]
```

You can clearly see that `HORSE` and `COW` are normalized. You'll need to do this again by switching the filler direction so you'll have `GOD` and `ET`:

Reverse direction: `np.array([np.pad(mearray[i], (i+1, leng-i), pad_with) for i in range(leng)])`

```
[['0' 'H' 'X' 'X' 'W' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'D' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' 'X' 'O' 'X' 'X' 'O' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'O' 'X' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' 'X' 'X' 'R' 'X' 'X' 'C' 'X' 'G' 'X' 'X' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'S' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'T' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'E' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'E' 'X' '0']]
```

Now you can see `GOD` and `ET` (upside down) in your matrix. You should be able to use your original function to retrieve them.

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 3):

If you do not care too much about the order in which all diagonals are traversed, this generator function in pure Python will do, making use of the fact that up-right is down-left backwards:

```
def rotate(row, n):
    return row[n:] + row[:n]

def diags(grid, rev=False):
    n = len(grid)
    _grid = [list(row) + [None]*(n-1) for row in grid]  # pad for rotation
    for diag in zip(*(rotate(_grid[i], (i, -i)[rev]) for i in range(n))):
        d = ''.join(filter(None, diag))
        yield from (d, d[::-1])
    if not rev:
        yield from diags(grid, rev=True) 

>>> list(diags(grid))
['H',
 'H',
 'XX',
 'XX',
 'XOX',
 'XOX',
 'WXXX',
 'XXXW',
 'XXRXX',
 'XXRXX',
 'XOXXX',
 'XXXOX',
 'XXXSX',
 'XSXXX',
 'XXCXX',
 'XXCXX',
 'XXXXE',
 'EXXXX',
 'DOGXX',
 'XXGOD',
 'XXXX',
 'XXXX',
 'XXX',
 'XXX',
 'TE',
 'ET',
 'X',
 'X',
 'HORSE',
 'ESROH',
 'XXXXX',
 'XXXXX',
 'XXXXX',
 'XXXXX',
 'WOCXX',
 'XXCOW',
 'XXXXE',
 'EXXXX',
 'XXGXX',
 'XXGXX',
 'XXXT',
 'TXXX',
 'XOX',
 'XOX',
 'XX',
 'XX',
 'D',
 'D',
 'X',
 'X',
 'XX',
 'XX',
 'XXX',
 'XXX',
 'XXXX',
 'XXXX']
```

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over all possible diagonals, you can use numpy [diagonal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html). Also use numpy `fliplr`, `flipud`, `flip` to get diagonals in all directions:

```
import numpy as np

grid = [
    "HXXWXXXXXD",
    "XOXXOXXXOX",
    "XXRXXCXGXX",
    "XXXSXXXXXT",
    "XXXXEXXXEX"]
data_orig = np.array(list(map(list, grid)))

transformations = {
    'Downwards and Right': np.array,
    'Downwards and left': np.fliplr,
    'Upwards and Right': np.flipud,
    'Upwards and left': np.flip,
}

for descr, trans in transformations.items():
    data = trans(data_orig)
    print(descr)
    print(data)
    offset_row = 1 - data.shape[0]
    offset_column = data.shape[1]
    for offset in range(offset_row, offset_column):
        print(data.diagonal(offset=offset))
```

Ouput:

```
Downwards and Right
[['H' 'X' 'X' 'W' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'D']
 ['X' 'O' 'X' 'X' 'O' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'O' 'X']
 ['X' 'X' 'R' 'X' 'X' 'C' 'X' 'G' 'X' 'X']
 ['X' 'X' 'X' 'S' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'T']
 ['X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'E' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'E' 'X']]
['X']
['X' 'X']
['X' 'X' 'X']
['X' 'X' 'X' 'X']
['H' 'O' 'R' 'S' 'E']
['X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X']
['X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X']
['W' 'O' 'C' 'X' 'X']
['X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'E']
['X' 'X' 'G' 'X' 'X']
['X' 'X' 'X' 'T']
['X' 'O' 'X']
['X' 'X']
['D']
Downwards and left
[['D' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'W' 'X' 'X' 'H']
 ['X' 'O' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'O' 'X' 'X' 'O' 'X']
 ['X' 'X' 'G' 'X' 'C' 'X' 'X' 'R' 'X' 'X']
 ['T' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'S' 'X' 'X' 'X']
 ['X' 'E' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'E' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X']]
['X']
['T' 'E']
['X' 'X' 'X']
['X' 'X' 'X' 'X']
['D' 'O' 'G' 'X' 'X']
['X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'E']
['X' 'X' 'C' 'X' 'X']
['X' 'X' 'X' 'S' 'X']
['X' 'O' 'X' 'X' 'X']
['X' 'X' 'R' 'X' 'X']
['W' 'X' 'X' 'X']
['X' 'O' 'X']
['X' 'X']
['H']
Upwards and Right
[['X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'E' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'E' 'X']
 ['X' 'X' 'X' 'S' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'T']
 ['X' 'X' 'R' 'X' 'X' 'C' 'X' 'G' 'X' 'X']
 ['X' 'O' 'X' 'X' 'O' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'O' 'X']
 ['H' 'X' 'X' 'W' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'D']]
['H']
['X' 'X']
['X' 'O' 'X']
['X' 'X' 'X' 'W']
['X' 'X' 'R' 'X' 'X']
['X' 'X' 'X' 'O' 'X']
['X' 'S' 'X' 'X' 'X']
['X' 'X' 'C' 'X' 'X']
['E' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X']
['X' 'X' 'G' 'O' 'D']
['X' 'X' 'X' 'X']
['X' 'X' 'X']
['E' 'T']
['X']
Upwards and left
[['X' 'E' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'E' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X']
 ['T' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'S' 'X' 'X' 'X']
 ['X' 'X' 'G' 'X' 'C' 'X' 'X' 'R' 'X' 'X']
 ['X' 'O' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'O' 'X' 'X' 'O' 'X']
 ['D' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'W' 'X' 'X' 'H']]
['D']
['X' 'X']
['X' 'O' 'X']
['T' 'X' 'X' 'X']
['X' 'X' 'G' 'X' 'X']
['E' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X']
['X' 'X' 'C' 'O' 'W']
['X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X']
['X' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X']
['E' 'S' 'R' 'O' 'H']
['X' 'X' 'X' 'X']
['X' 'X' 'X']
['X' 'X']
['X']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each character, and if the character is part of a word, then each possibility (vertical, horizontal, right-diag, left-diag) can be checked:

```
from collections import namedtuple
d = ['HXXWXXXXXD', 'XOXXOXXXOX', 'XXRXXCXGXX', 'XXXSXXXXXT', 'XXXXEXXXEX']
node = namedtuple('node', ['val', 'ischar'])
_d = [[node(i, i != 'X') for i in b] for b in d]
def traverse(_func, _start, _board):
  while True:
    try:
       _a, _b = _func(*_start)
       if not _board[_a][_b].ischar:
         break
       _start = [_a, _b]
       yield _board[_a][_b].val
    except:
       break

def get_words(board, *args):
  funcs = [[lambda x, y:(x-1, y), lambda x, y:(x+1, y)], [lambda x, y:(x, y+1), lambda x, y:(x, y-1)], [lambda x:(x-1, y-1), lambda x, y:(x+1, y+1)], [lambda x, y:(x-1, y+1), lambda x, y:(x+1, y-1)]]
  for _s1, _s2 in funcs:
     yield ''.join(traverse(_s1, args, board))+board[args[0]][args[1]].val+''.join(traverse(_s2, args, board))


def words(board, to_find):
  for i in range(len(board)):
    for b in range(len(board[0])):
      if board[i][b].ischar:
        for word in get_words(board, i, b):
          if word in to_find:
            yield word
          if word[::-1] in to_find:
            yield word[::-1] 

print(list(set(words(_d, ["HORSE","COW","DOG","ET"]))))
```

Output:

```
['DOG', 'ET', 'HORSE', 'COW']
```